# Scrolling div content to the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll, scrolltop

I'm using `HTML5` for mobile apps. I have page with a scrollable list (using `iScroll4`).Each time the list loads at beginning if I want to read the last `<li>` I should scrool it to the end.

I want to make a page where the list will be loaded scrolled to the buttom, from the start.

I'm using `jQuery` method `scrollTop` to scroll to bottom of the DIV.
`divContent` is a scrollbar div, after I initialize the page on loading page I use:

```
  $('#demoPage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        $('#divContent').scrollTop($('#divContent')[0].scrollHeight);
  });
```

It's doing the job,but after that I can't scroll it again,it's not scrollable like before. Any ideas or new stuff that can handle this thing?

Comment: unclear of what you're trying to do

Comment: By the way, as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated.  You should be using the `.on()` method instead. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @RobW What exactly you didn't understand?

Comment: Is `$('#divContent')` set to use the `iScroll4`? If so, there is a `scrollToElement` method: `$("#divContent").scrollToElement('li:last-child', 100)`

Comment: It's not working for me, maybe other options?